# How do we get iframes to allow state changes to reflect in our components?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, iframe, ngxs

I'm building a component that uses an `<iframe>` to display another component.  This component connects to an NGXS state which needs to reflect changes made to the state.  After a lot of failures and testing I discovered the component will always only load the default settings of the state.  I created a `<button>` to toggle a boolean and added an `*ngIf` to the `<iframe>` so I can force it to reload manually after trying things like `this.Frame.(contentDocument || contentWindow).location.reload(true);` didn't make any difference.

I created a [stablitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y9puxy?file=src/app/app.component.html) to demonstrate this issue however I think stackblitz blocks the use of `<iframe>`s in their platform so you might need to copy it into a local project to tinker with it.  It's a simple app that shows the state outside of the `<iframe>` as well as inside with a button that toggles the `<iframe>` on and off so you can see how only the default values load after you update the value I have available for demonstration purposes.  I'm not getting any type of errors and the issue isn't a matter of something being wrong with the code so I don't know what more to show that isn't in the stackblitz.

Does anybody know why and how `<iframe>`s do this and if there's a way around it?  The only thing I can think to try is make a NestJS app to see if putting the data outside the app and making an API request from the component inside the `<iframe>` will be allowed, however I don't know why this issue is occurring to in turn know if that too won't be rejected for that same reason.  How this can be handled?

Answer (score 0):

The document running in an iframe is isolated from its host. They do not share memory- Angular does not provide a way to synchronize state between a host and an iframe on the page out of the box. The example is actually booting two Angular apps (one inside the frame and one outside). If you are using an iframe for security and isolation purposes, you'll need to devise a way to pass state between the host and the child via [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) (and be aware that you are running two copies of your application). If this isn't for security/isolation, simply do not use an iframe to contain the child component.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: ok but how do I set up the component to take the data passed into the `postMessage`?